# Why the mesh has been marked as non-accessible when adding MeshCollider from assetBundle and how to solve it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, accessible, scriptable

I have a scriptable asset containing a fxbModel on a GameObject variable and with it i'am doing this:

```
model = Instantiate(caAsset.model, origin);
fbxComponents.All(fbxComponent => fbxComponent.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>());
```

Is the asset loaded from Ressources, everything works well.*

But is the asset from a AssetBundle** the following error occurs.

```
CollisionMeshData couldn't be created because the mesh has been marked as non-accessible. 
Mesh asset path "" Mesh name "Flanschdeckel_low"
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
```

(*)
`MyScriptableAsset caAsset = Resources.Load(scriptableObjectName);`

(**)
`MyScriptableAsset caAsset = bundle.LoadAsset<MyScriptableAsset>(scriptableObjectName);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a read/write enabled property on fbx files on the model tab under mesh sub text if you tick that box it'll probably work. Check right corner on image for better understanding.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Vi2.png)

Comment: Yes, that makes the trick. Thank you.
I found out, that unity further has this checkbox checked on fbx import.

I have not found a way to edit this setting, but with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-isReadable.html it is possible to control the process of creating asset bundles by informing the user who is creating the asset.